# Problems returning database information with MongoDB, Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const express = require('express');
const second = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myorders';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("The connection was awesome");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
  second.get('/Students',(req,res) => {
  const findStudents = function(db,call) {
  const collection = db.collection('Students');
    collection.find({}).toArray(function (err,result) {
     if (!err) {
       res.send(result)
     } else {
         console.log(err);
         call(err);
     }
});
}
});
client.close();
});
second.listen(3200,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = second;
```

So I am trying to display my mongodb information on a web server and here are the screen shots

[image]

Above is the MongoDB collection of students and marks 
[image]

And above is my Node.js command prompt and I get a deprecation warning. Is there any way I can fix it? Is there any other error why I can't display the information in the web server?

Comment: So your question is how to fix the deprecation warnings?

Comment: why don't you use mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this deprecation warning, all you need is to do what it says: pass the option `useNewUrlParse: true` in the options object to `MongoClient.connect`. So the line where you connect to MongoDB database would be:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParse: true }, function(err, client)
```

Anyway, this is just a warning, not a blocking error, and your app is running. I think there are several things wrong in your code, mainly that you declare the function to be executed on the GET to /Students within the callback of the connection to the database and that you close that connection so that the data could no longer be accessed. I think this code should work for you:

```
const express = require('express');
const second = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'myorders';
let db;

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    db = client.db(dbName);
    console.log("The connection was awesome");
});

second.listen(3200, () => {
    console.log('We got it running');
});


second.get('/Students', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('Students').find().toArray((err,result) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(result)
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

If you think that the database should not be always opened, yous should connect and close at each request to /Students, this way:

```
second.listen(3200, () => {
    console.log('We got it running');
});


second.get('/Students', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);

        db = client.db(dbName);
        db.collection('Students').find().toArray((err,result) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(result)
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            client.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the benefit of closing the database connection at each request?  I've read in quite a few places that it's best to leave the database connection open as opposed to opening and closing it for each request.

Comment: Also, any idea how to export "db" when the http request is in a separate router file?  For some reason, my code shows db as undefined outside the MongoClient.connect section.  Any idea why?

Comment: First of all, if you think my answer solves your initial problem, I'd appreciate it if you'd upvote it and mark it as correct. Regarding your new questions: 1- I think you should leave the connection always open but as I saw you were closing it I edited my answer to add that option. 2- Of course, you should export the `db` variable to access it from another controller. I always have a file from which I connect to a database and export the connection variable to make the requests from where it corresponds.